# SQL Server Selecting data from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a table for reports which is made up from data from other tables. The Reports table needs to include info of how many holiday hours and sick hours each site is taken but the employees take hours individually. All these table are connected by foreign key relationship.

[dbo].[Employee]:

```
EmployeeID  |Name            |SiteID         |
------------+----------------+---------------+
1           | Joe            |1              |
2           | Tom            |2              |
3           | Mary           |3              |
4           | Bill           |1              |
5           | 16             |2              |
```

Site:

[dbo].[Site]:

```
SiteID      |Site Name       |
------------+----------------+
1           | SiteA          |
2           | SiteB          |
3           | SiteC          |
```

[dbo].[HolidayRequestForm]:

```
EmployeeID  |HolidayHours           |
------------+----------------+
1           | 8              |
2           | 16             |
3           | 16             |
```

[dbo].[SickLeaveRequestForm]:

```
EmployeeID  |SickHours           |
------------+----------------+
1           | 8              |
2           | 8              |
3           | 8              |
```

I have tried achieve this by using joins and then selecting the relevant data from the different tables, but I'm having no luck.

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Employee]  
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[Site]
     ON [dbo].[Site].SiteID = [dbo].[Employee].SiteID
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[HolidayRequestForm]
              LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SickLeaveRequestForm]
                ON [dbo].[SickLeaveRequestForm].EmployeeID = [dbo]. 
[HolidayRequestForm].EmployeeID
     GROUP BY [dbo].[Site].SiteName
```

Would I be better off creating a view?

Here is the desired result!

```
SiteName  |Holiday Hours   |Sick Hours
 ---------+----------------+---------------+
Site A    | 8              |8              |
Site B    | 16             |8              |
Site C    | 16             |8              |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre trying to select all the columns from a query that is grouping - you can only select columns that are grouped, or appear in an aggregate function:

```
SELECT s.SiteName, SUM(hrf.HolidayHours) as SumHolidayHours, SUM(slrf.SickHours) as SumSickHours
FROM 
   [dbo].[Employee] e 
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[Site] s
     ON s.SiteID = e.SiteID
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[HolidayRequestForm] hrf
     ON hrf.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeID
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SickLeaveRequestForm] slrf
     ON slrf.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
 GROUP BY s.SiteName
```

You were missing an ON condition to one of your joins. I've also added table aliases to reduce the visual clutter and converted both the joins to the hours tables into being left joins just in case an employee doesn't have any records in those tables

The important thing to appreciate about grouping queries is that multiple records with the same combination of values in the grouped columns (your sitename) will be collapsed into a single record in the output. The aggregate function (SUM MAX MIN AVG etc) defines what to do with all the detailed data as it collapses. In this case we are trying to add up the hours by site. The association is

```
site -> employees -> hours (sick and holiday)
```

Because there are multiple employees and possibly also multiple hours, but we're grouping on site name, there will be only one row per site in the output, so we need to specify an aggregation to carry out on the other columns. You can't select * from a grouping query, because you can't include all the columns; you can only include columns that are part of th grouping combination, or an aggregate of the data that went into the group. If you ever want to add more columns to a group query but you don't want to have the group broken down into more fine detail on the grouping keys, you have to instead join the grouped data back to the main tables to get the additional data

Comment: Great, the query was completed successfully, but I'm quite confused as the numbers seem to be incorrect! I tried you answers and PSK's answer and they both came out with different a incorrect sums

Comment: The query I posted works with the example data you posted to produce the desired result you posted. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=53381adcb915938d891d4b2371bab4ba

Comment: Okay cool! I'll have a look at my data! thanks!! especially for the additional information

Comment: If you remove the GROUP BY and do a `SELECT *` instead on your live db then you'll see all the data that was summed up; export it to excel and check the sums - they should definitely be the same (excel vs sqlserver GROUP BY)

Comment: My query and PSKs could return different results if, for example, an employee had some Holiday Hours but no record in Sick Hours. The lack of a record in SickHours would cause PSK's query to eliminate the HolidayHours record from the results (INNER JOIN on sick hours causes the row to disappear if there is no sick hours). THis would result in lower sums than expected. I used LEFT join so that the site/employee/holiday row data remains, and SickHours will become NULL if that employee has no sickhours row. This means HolidayHours will still be added in for that emp. SUM(null) works like SUM(0)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT dbo.Site.SiteName,
    SUM(dbo.HolidayRequestForm.HolidayHours) AS HolidayHours,
    SUM(dbo.SickLeaveRequestForm.SickHours) AS SickHours
FROM dbo.Employee INNER JOIN
    dbo.Site ON dbo.Employee.SiteID = dbo.Site.SiteID INNER JOIN
    dbo.HolidayRequestForm ON dbo.Employee.EmployeeID = 
    dbo.HolidayRequestForm.EmployeeID INNER JOIN
    dbo.SickLeaveRequestForm ON dbo.Employee.EmployeeID = dbo.SickLeaveRequestForm.EmployeeID
GROUP BY dbo.Site.SiteName
```

*Would I be better off creating a view?*
It all depends if this is a one-time query or you are going to use that for reporting on a regular basis.

Also if you want to include all Sites where no employes have taken sick leave or holiday (e.g. for MSSQL):

```
SELECT  dbo.Site.SiteName, 
    { fn IFNULL(SUM(dbo.HolidayRequestForm.HolidayHours), 0) } AS HolidayHours, 
    { fn IFNULL(SUM(dbo.SickLeaveRequestForm.SickHours), 0) } AS SickHours
FROM dbo.Employee 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.HolidayRequestForm ON dbo.Employee.EmployeeID = dbo.HolidayRequestForm.EmployeeID 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SickLeaveRequestForm ON dbo.Employee.EmployeeID = dbo.SickLeaveRequestForm.EmployeeID 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Site ON dbo.Employee.SiteID = dbo.Site.SiteID
GROUP BY dbo.Site.SiteName
```

Comment: Regular Reports!

Comment: Not sure in what context and what db you are using but view should give you convenience and speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUM` aggregate function with `GROUP BY` like following query.

```
SELECT s.sitename, 
       Sum(hf.holidayhours) AS HolidayHours, 
       Sum(sl.sickhours)       AS SickHours 
FROM   [dbo].[site] s 
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[employee] e 
               ON s.siteid = e.siteid 
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[holidayrequestform] hf 
               ON e.employeeid = hf.employeeid 
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[sickleaverequestform] sl 
               ON sl.employeeid = e.employeeid 
GROUP  BY s.sitename
```

**Note**:

1. `*` doesn't go with `GROUP BY`, any non aggregated column you want
   in select should present in your `GROUP BY`
2. As a best practice, you should use alias names for your tables while
   joining.

Comment: thanks the query worked but the sums are coming out incorrect!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below query.

```
create table Employee(EmployeeID int, Name varchar(20), SiteID int)
insert into Employee values
(1, 'Joe', 1),
(2, 'Tom', 2),
(3, 'Mary', 3),
(4, 'Bill', 1),
(5, '16', 2)

create table [Site] (SiteID int, [Site Name] Varchar(20))
insert into [Site] Values
(1, 'SiteA'),
(2, 'SiteB'),
(3, 'SiteC')

Create table HolidayRequestForm(EmployeeID  int, HolidayHours int)
insert into HolidayRequestForm Values
(1, 8),
(2, 16),
(3, 16)

Create table SickLeaveRequestForm(EmployeeID int, SickHours int)
insert into SickLeaveRequestForm Values
(1 ,8),
(2,8),
(3,8)

Select [Site Name], SUM(HolidayHours) as HolidayHours, SUM(SickHours) as 
SickHours
from(
Select 
[Site].[Site Name], HolidayRequestForm.HolidayHours, SickLeaveRequestForm.SickHours
from [Site]
inner join Employee on [Site].SiteId = Employee.SiteId
inner join HolidayRequestForm on HolidayRequestForm.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID
inner join SickLeaveRequestForm on Employee.EmployeeID = SickLeaveRequestForm.EmployeeID
)a group by [Site Name]
```